# Can't upload data to s3 from a tool called Vector.dev

Tags: amazon-s3, vectordotdev

**I am using a tool called vector.dev to upload the data from local to S3 but not able to upload data to s3 Please help and let me know what changes are required to push it to s3 **
**The Things I have commented is for the sake so that I can just do a
bulk upload and see if it goes on to s3**

```
 data_dir = "/var/lib/vector"

 # Ingest data by tailing one or more files
 [sources.apache_newLogs]
 type         = "file"
 include      = ["/Users/adityaverma/Downloads/ApplicationLogs/appLog/newest2.log"]    # supports gl    obbing
 ignore_older = 86400                         # 1 day

 Structure and parse the data
 [transforms.apache_parser]
 inputs       = ["apache_logs"]
 #  type         = "regex_parser"                # fast/powerful regex
 #  patterns     = ['^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}']

 # patterns      = ['^(?P<host>[w.]+) - (?P<user>[w]+) (?P<bytes_in>[d]+) [(?P<timestamp>.*)] "(?P<me    thod>[w]+) (?P<path>.*)" (?P<status>[d]+) (?P<bytes_out>[d]+)$']

 # Sample the data to save on cost
 #[transforms.apache_sampler]
 #  inputs       = ["apache_parser"]
 #  type         = "sampler"
 #  rate         = 50                            # only keep 50%

 # Send structured data to a short-term storage
 #[sinks.es_cluster]
 #  inputs       = ["apache_sampler"]            # only take sampled data
 #  type         = "elasticsearch"
 #  host         = "http://79.12.221.222:9200"   # local or external host
 #  index        = "vector-%Y-%m-%d"             # daily indices

 # Send structured data to a cost-effective long-term storage
  [sinks.s3_archives]
inputs       = ["apache_newLogs"]             # don't sample for S3
type         = "aws_s3"
region       = "ap-south-1"
bucket       = "my-bucket-bang"
key_prefix   = "date=%Y-%m-%d"               # daily partitions, hive friendly format
compression  = "gzip"                        # compress final objects
encoding     = "ndjson"                      # new line delimited JSON
[sinks.s3_archives.batch]
max_size   = 10000000                      # 10mb uncompressed
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error says health check passed

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Have you tried starting "vector top" and check if the events are being processed by the s3 sink step?